# Chart.js is it possible to fire javascript when clicking on point on the graph?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Does anyone know if it is possible to fire a javascript event when clicking on a point on a Chart.js graph?

If so, how?

UPDATE: This is my current chart initialization script, based on feedback:

```
function RenderBasicAnalyticsChart(targetSelector, usersCreated, usersAuthenticated, contentDownloaded)
{
    var ctx = $(targetSelector);
    var chartObject = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Users created',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0,169,224,1.0)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,169,224,1.0)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,169,224,0.4)',
                    data: usersCreated
                },
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Users signed in',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(120,170,0,1.0)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(120,170,0,1.0)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(120,170,0,0.4)',
                    data: usersAuthenticated
                },
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Assets downloaded',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255,106,19,1.0)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,106,19,1.0)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,106,19,0.4)',
                    data: contentDownloaded
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            defaultFontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            responsiveAnimationDuration: 100,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        }
    });

    $(targetSelector).click(function (e) {
        var activePoints = chartObject.getElementsAtEvent(event);
        if (activePoints.length > 0) {
            var clickedDatasetIndex = activePoints[0]._datasetIndex;
            var clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
            var value = chartObject.data.datasets[clickedDatasetIndex].data[clickedElementIndex];
            console.log(clickedDatasetIndex + ' - ' + value['x']);
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I am now having is that my *clickedDatasetIndex* is always coming back as 0, regardless of which line I clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you sure can!  Just use the [`.getDatasetAtEvent(e)`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) or [`.getElementsAtEvent(e)`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) prototype methods (depending on your needs).  Here is more detail on what they do.

> Looks for the element under the event point, then returns all elements at the same data index. This is used internally for 'label' mode highlighting.
>
> Calling getElementsAtEvent(event) on your Chart instance passing an argument of an event, or jQuery event, will return the point elements that are at that the same position of that event.

Here is an example for how to get the point that was clicked when there are more than 1 datasets.  Assuming my canvas has an id of `canvas` and my chart instance is called `myLine`.

```
document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = function(evt){
  var activePoints = myLine.getElementAtEvent(event);

  // make sure click was on an actual point
  if (activePoints.length > 0) {
    var clickedDatasetIndex = activePoints[0]._datasetIndex;
    var clickedElementindex = activePoints[0]._index;
    var label = myLine.data.labels[clickedElementindex];
    var value = myLine.data.datasets[clickedDatasetIndex].data[clickedElementindex];     
    alert("Clicked: " + label + " - " + value);
  }
};
```

You can also experiment with this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqvLNx).

Comment: Thanks.  This looks super helpful!  I will try this out on my code in the next few days.

Comment: as you may note I have multiple datasets.   How do I detect which one I have clicked on?  With the example you gave -- which was super helpful -- it assumes one dataset.

Comment: Its very similar, let me update my example to demonstrate this.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Check out my updated answer.  It now shows how to deal with multiple datasets.  I updated the codepen example for you too.

Comment: It works correctly in the codepen example. Are you clicking on actual points or just the line?

Comment: The actual points.  Yup, your codepen example works, but mine doesn't.   Confused.   See my updated code above.

Comment: You are still using `getElementsAtEvent` but I switched to `getElementAtEvent`.  The difference is the first one returns both datasets always but the second only returns the dataset that you actually clicked.  Sorry, I should have been more explicit about that change.

Comment: Ha, I totally did not catch that tiny one letter change. :-)   Working now!